# Как записать в массив вывод из базы данных на Python?

Tags: python, база-данных

У меня есть следующий код на python:

```
from sqlalchemy import text
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine=create_engine('mysql://******:*****@***********/*', echo=False)
connect=engine.connect()
query_1=text(
    "select id, action from instance_actions "
    "where instance_uuid like :e1 "
)
result_1=connect.execute(query_1,e1='*****').fetchall()
print result_1
poz=[('create'), ('start'), ('restart')]
```

Как можно записать вывод из базы в массив и найти поочередно такие же элементы как в массиве poz[]?

Answer (score 1):

Если под записью вы имеете в виду сохранение в какой-либо контейнер для последующего использования, под массивом — список, значения из *poz* хранятся в колонке *action*, и решить задачу фильтрации вы хотите почему-то не при помощи SQL, а в Питоне, то примерно так:

```
matches = [row for row in result_1 if row['action'] in poz]
```